# Run some PHP code from other file

Tags: php

I have two files:

In `a.php`:

```
<?php echo "one"; include 'b.php'; echo "three"; ?>
```

In `b.php`:

```
<?php echo"one"; echo"two"; echo"three"; echo"four"; echo"five"; ?>
```

My question is how get only `echo"two";` from `b.php` and what I must write in `a.php`?

Comment: `echo"two";` should probably be in a function if you want to re-use it.

Answer (score 1):

To include other PHP files into another, add this to your code

```
   include('otherfile.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just retrieve a port of the code, including the file will execute the whole file. You could use function do this:

```
// File function.php
<?php
function a() {
    echo 'one';
}

function b() {
    echo 'two';
}

// File index.php
include('function.php');
a(); // will echo one
```

Here's a proper way to accomplish what you want.